# Mongoid 1.9.2 + Rails 2.3: Errors with BSON::OrderedHash being returned instead of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, bson

## Rails 2.3.11 application

## Mongoid 1.9.2 (latest "legacy" branch)

Since there's no documentation for Mongoid 1.X branch anymore, I'm struggling with what I've got
configured wrong in this example.  It seems I'm not querying an embedded document correctly.  How
should I be doing it instead?

```
class GraphLink
  include Mongoid::Document  
  embedded_in :graph_pages, :inverse_of => :graph_links  
end 

class GraphInlink
  include Mongoid::Document  
  embedded_in :graph_pages, :inverse_of => :graph_inlinks  
end

class GraphPage
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :graph_links
  embeds_many :graph_inlinks

  def add_relationship(link) 
    unless has_link?(url)
      self.graph_links << GraphLink.new(link)
      destination_page = GraphPage.where(:url => link[:url]).first
      destination_page.graph_links << GraphInlinks.new(link)
      destination_page.save
      self.save
    end
  end

  def has_link?(url)
    graph_links.where(:url => url).count > 0
  end

end
```

At the console, I type

```
a = GraphPage.new(page_data_1)
a.add_relationship(link1)
```

And it returns

```
Error : NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for BSON::OrderedHash:0x00000114c1e8e0
```

with the error being the "has_link?" query.

Help!

Comment: The older Mongoid Docs can be found at http://two.mongoid.org/ hurry and read before they're gone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you can't compose queries like that. Perhaps try

```
def has_link?(url)
  graph_links.any? { |doc| doc.url == url }
end
```